# How can I find nearest matching time from the same table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to match the start and end times a user watches a TV show from a single data table in Google BigQuery, but I'm not sure how to do this because I keep getting an error saying, "Table name cannot be resolved: dataset name is missing."

Events table

```
user_id  show_id   event_type  logtime
-------  --------  ----------  -----------------------
 john      123       start     2016-08-01 06:00:00 UTC
 john      123       start     2016-08-01 06:15:00 UTC
 john      123       end       2016-08-01 06:10:00 UTC
 john      123       end       2016-08-01 06:16:00 UTC
```

Desired results

```
user_id  show_id   start_time                end_time
-------  --------  -----------------------   -----------------------
 john      123     2016-08-01 06:00:00 UTC   2016-08-01 06:10:00 UTC
 john      123     2016-08-01 06:15:00 UTC   2016-08-01 06:16:00 UTC
```

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT user_id, show_id, st.logtime AS start_time, et.logtime AS end_time
  FROM 
    (SELECT user_id, show_id, logtime FROM events WHERE event_type = 'start') AS st 
  JOIN 
    (SELECT user_id, show_id, logtime FROM events WHERE event_type = 'end') AS et 
  ON 
    st.logtime = (SELECT min(logtime) FROM events WHERE event_type = 'end') 
      AND st.user_id = et.user_id AND st.show_id = et.show_id
```

Mikhail's answer seems to work the best after validating a few examples, but...

```
SELECT 
  user_id, show_id,  
  logtime AS start_time,
  next_logtime AS end_time
FROM (
  SELECT 
    user_id, show_id, event_type, logtime,
    LEAD(logtime) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, show_id ORDER BY logtime) AS next_logtime,
    LEAD(event_type) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, show_id ORDER BY logtime) AS next_event_type
  FROM events 
)
WHERE event_type = 'start'
AND next_event_type = 'end'
```

I don't know how to incorporate logic to handle consecutive instances of the same event_type. For example:

```
event_type  logtime
----------  ------------------------
 start     2016-08-01 09:20:00 UTC
 start     2016-08-01 09:23:00 UTC
 start     2016-08-01 09:24:00 UTC
 end       2016-08-01 09:24:00 UTC
 end       2016-08-01 09:24:00 UTC
```

In this scenario, I'd like to keep the earliest start time, 09:20, and the earliest end time, 09:24 (I think this makes sense...).

Comment: Focus on the error message.  What happens if you try this?  `select count(1) x from events where 1=2`?

Comment: Am I supposed to run this query literally? I got a "0" as a result.

Comment: Yes you were.  It quickly told you that the problem is not with the table named `events`.  Continue this approach with the subqueries until you find the source of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below

```
SELECT 
  user_id, show_id,  
  logtime AS start_time,
  next_logtime AS end_time
FROM (
  SELECT 
    user_id, show_id, event_type, logtime,
    LEAD(logtime) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, show_id ORDER BY logtime) AS next_logtime
  FROM events 
)
WHERE event_type = 'start'
```

> Unfortunately, the data is pretty dirty, so there are events that may have a start time but no end time and vice versa

below example ignores start without end and vice versa
can be ajusted to whatever logic you have in mind though

```
SELECT 
  user_id, show_id,  
  logtime AS start_time,
  next_logtime AS end_time
FROM (
  SELECT 
    user_id, show_id, event_type, logtime,
    LEAD(logtime) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, show_id ORDER BY logtime) AS next_logtime,
    LEAD(event_type) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, show_id ORDER BY logtime) AS next_event_type
  FROM events 
)
WHERE event_type = 'start'
AND next_event_type = 'end'
```

> I'd like to keep the earliest start time, 09:20, and the earliest end time

```
SELECT 
  user_id, show_id, 
  MIN(start_time) AS start_time,
  MAX(end_time) AS end_time
FROM (
  SELECT 
    user_id, show_id,  
    logtime AS start_time,
    next_logtime AS end_time,
    SUM(event_type <> next_event_type) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, show_id ORDER BY logtime ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING  ) AS grp
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      user_id, show_id, event_type, logtime,
      LEAD(logtime) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, show_id ORDER BY logtime) AS next_logtime,
      LEAD(event_type) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, show_id ORDER BY logtime) AS next_event_type,
    FROM events 
  )
  WHERE event_type = 'start'
)
GROUP BY user_id, show_id, grp
```

Comment: I don't see how you assign end_time to logtimes with an event_type of "end".

Comment: I assume each start event has respective end event! as it is in your simplified example. if it is not a case - you should define logic of how to treat such case. what to do when two consecutive  starts are in place

Comment: added another example to handle missing start / end pair

Comment: added yet another example  - hope this is last one!

Answer (score 0):

If your data really lines up, you can enumerate the start and end times and use that for aggregation:

```
select user_id, show_id, ,
       max(case when event_type = 'start' then logtime end) as logtime_start,
       max(case when event_type = 'end' then logtime end) as logtime_end
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id, show_id, event_type orer by logtime) as seqnum
      from events e
     ) e
group by user_id, show_id, seqnum;
```

This works for the data in your question.  If the events are properly paired, then it should work fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, the data is pretty dirty, so there are events that may have a start time but no end time and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id, show_id, st.logtime AS start_time, MIN(et.logtime) AS end_time
FROM 
(SELECT user_id, show_id, time AS logtime FROM events WHERE event_type = 'start') AS st , 
(SELECT user_id, show_id, time AS logtime  FROM events WHERE event_type = 'end') AS et 
WHERE st.logtime < et.logtime, st.user_id = et.user_id, st.show_id = et.show_id
GROUP BY st.logtime
```

1. This will make a cartesian product of the two select queries with
   start logtime and end logtime.
2. filter the values where start logtime < end logtime.
3. group rows with same start logtime and min of end logtime.